# Sybase internal tables for ORM generation

Tags: sybase, perl

I am working on a Perl application that uses [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aSchema%3a%3aLoader) in order to generate the ORM layer of the application, against a Sybase ASE 15.5 database.

We recently migrated from Sybase 12.1, where the ORM generation worked fine, to our current database, where things have gone screwy.  Our ORM layer doesn't change much, so this wasn't immediately apparent.

The driver for accessing the database information uses the syscomments, sysobjects, syscolumns, and systypes tables, but I can't find any reference to them in the ASE 15.5 [system table documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/CEGIEEAF.htm).

Searching through the documentation has led me to conjecture that these tables were retired sometime around 15.1, but I don't have enough expertise to be able to comment either way.  Does anyone know where this information is stored in 15.5?

Answer (score 1):

Those tables are still in ASE 15.5

[syscolumns](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X14340.htm)

[syscomments](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X19576.htm)

[sysobjects](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X14933.htm)

[systypes](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/X37714.htm)

Comment: Wow, that's reassuring to know.  I suppose now I need to see if 15.5 stores entries in syscomments differently than 12.x.

Comment: Extracting SP text from syscomments is always going to be a pain. I tend to use a shell script + [defncopy](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/X73292.htm) when I need to see SP text.